# API Send only New/Updated/Deleted records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, version-control, updates, server-side

I'm actually working on a Rails Application API. I have models with a lot of data.

I would like to be able from my client application to send like a Token, a timestamp or whatever to get the new, updated, deleted content/datas since the last request. While providing a new Token, timestamp for the futur request.

In that way, I have just to update my local cached content on the client side depending on the result of the request rather than update all of my local datas at each request.

After many researches on Google, I didn't find anything convincing.

I don't now how can I manage that on the server side ? Is that a good practice ?
If yes what's the best way to do it ?